# Player's name isn't showing Unity3d/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script where at launch, you have to set your players name. After you hit OK, it goes to Main Menu and has a BoxInfo, where players name is shown.

But it seems like it doesn't want to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Here are the important pieces from the code:

```
public Text PlayerNameText;
public Text ErrorPlayerNameText;
public InputField PlayerNameInput;

    public void SetPlayerName()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlayerNameInput.text))
        {
            ErrorPlayerNameText.CrossFadeAlpha(1, 0.7f, true);
            return;
        }

        ErrorPlayerNameText.CrossFadeAlpha(0, 0.5f, true);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(UMW_Keys.PlayerName, PlayerNameInput.text);

#if  UNITY_5_2 || UNITY_5_3 || UNITY_5_4
        int nameSize = 10;
#else
        int nameSize = 40;
#endif
        PlayerNameText.text = string.Format("PLAYER NAME: <size=" + nameSize + "><color=#00ffd8>{0}</color></size>", PlayerNameInput.text);
        Manager.GoToWindow("MainMenu");
    }
```

BoxInfo game object in hierarchy has a Layer of UI and has a child game object called Text with Text (script) and text:
 *"PLAYER NAME:
MY NAME"*

Not sure where I missed the code, but in theory, it should all work fine!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmm, I tried troubleshooting it myself, by adding "string testName = "testName" and replacing PlayerNameInput.text with testName and it didn't work either. Now I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind -_-
Found a solution myself.

```
int nameSize
```

Was too big that it did't show in Unity's UI. lol